# the 4th order linear ode with 3 initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading a paper in which it deals with an ODE defined by
$$
f''''(x)+f(x)-1=0
$$
for $x\in[0,+\infty)$ where $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$. Then it says trivially we can have a 'unique' solution
$$
f(x)=1+\sqrt{2}e^{-t/\sqrt{2}}\cos\left(\frac t{\sqrt{2}}+\frac \pi4\right)
$$

I am a bit confused. Should we have four initial conditions to have an exact solution for a forth order ODE? How this paper obtain such solution?

You may find the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05115v1.pdf), page 5, equation (3.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other two components of the homogeneous solution are
$$
A·e^{t/\sqrt{2}}\cos\left(\frac t{\sqrt{2}}+\frac \pi4\right)+B·e^{t/\sqrt{2}}\sin\left(\frac t{\sqrt{2}}+\frac \pi4\right)
$$
If either of the coefficients is non-zero, you get an exponentially growing function.

Comment: ah yea... stupid me! I got it. Since they are dealing with an minimizing problem so they are forcing to take $A=B=0$. Thank you.

Comment: By the way sir, can you expand your answer a bit to include that how you write done the general solution for such ODE?

Comment: and what if I deal with $-f^{(6)}+f-1=0$ with in addition that $f''(0)=0$?

Comment: Set $g(x)=f(x)-1$, then $g''''+g=0$ is homogeneous with characteristic polynomial $λ^4+1=0$ which has roots $λ=\frac1{\sqrt2}(\pm1\pmi)$. -- The second example would have $-λ^6+1=0$, $λ=e^{ik\frac\pi3}$, $k=0,1,...,5$. -- In the homogeneous solution components $C·e^{λt}$ remember that $e^{(a+ib)t}=e^{at}·(\cos(bt)+i\sin(bt))$ and that the complex  solutions of real equations come in conjugate pairs.